# How often does an app make an API call when it has the #4 error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So the (#4) error for those who need the reminder is: "Application request limit reached"

I actually use my App to build websites. I make a call, cache the data and display it. The default update time for my app used to be once every 6 hours it'd make an API call, GET {page-name-id}.

However, when this error started happening to my app I changed the call time from 6 hours to 1 year. Quite the change.

My question is it's been 2 weeks since I made that change and i'm still above my API limit. Granted, my usage seems to be decreasing but I need to get a good idea in my head how fast it is decreasing. So my question:

What is the default refresh time for an app that's got the #4 error?

I'm thinking it can't be using my defined refresh time of 1 year for two reasons:

- Some sites that have the #4 error do seem to get their call through and then act fine. Even though they've update within the last year. So it's definitely recalling. (Possibly due to #4 error causing my cache of old data to be deleted?)
- If every single one of my broken sites had the error and were using 1 year per call, there's no reason I can think of my API usage would be in use at all let alone +1000% of my limit.

Comment: _“it can't be using my defined refresh time of 1 year”_ - no clue what you are even talking about here – what exactly did you define in that regard and where …?

Comment: My app makes a call, caches the data and then displays it. It'll then after "x" amount of seconds, which I set, make another call and recreate the cache. 

Therefore, my defined cache refresh time is 1 year. 

It's all set in the backend of my server. 

But as I said above, it appears to be ignoring this and using some sort of default refresh time. Which I imagine is because of the #4 error.

Comment: So your question is actually about your - apparently broken – cache system, and not the Facebook API (?)

Comment: I doubt it's my cache system. Been working for multiple years. 

The recent wave of Facebook limitations on Apps without users resulting in my app suddenly being above API usage is the cause of the problem. I'm trying to remedy it. My question is in regards to whether or not there's a default error / retry timer for that #4 error.

It's definitely using some sort of call retry timer or something. Otherwise there'd be no reason my sites are using API calls rights now. This code works, once it's made a call it won't call again for a year. But sites have been making calls if it failed.

Comment: Rate limiting is based on a 24 hour interval, for the most part.